# How to get current variation data inside raw_woocommerce_price hook?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I'd like to get current variation data inside the raw_woocommerce_price hook.

```
function filter_raw_woocommerce_price( $price_1 ) {
    global $product;

    // Some custom code to change price by variation factor
    $variation_id = product->Something_I_Need_To_Know_To_Get_Current_Variation();

    // bla bla bla
    $factor = PutSomeCustomCalculationHere($variation_id);
    $price_1 = $price_1 * $factor;

    return $price_1;
};

add_filter( 'raw_woocommerce_price', 'filter_raw_woocommerce_price', 10, 1 );
```

How can I achieve that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

use this code, if the product is ok type use your custom logic like this:

```
add_filter( 'raw_woocommerce_price', array( $this, 'asdfasdadf' ) );
function asdfasdadf($price){
    global $product;
    // check if that is var product
    if( ! $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) return $price;
    // get variable data!
    var_dump( $product->get_attributes() ); exit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I only got an array with not enough information go to further : Array
(
    [pa_support] => Array
        (
            [name] => pa_support
            [value] => 
            [position] => 0
            [is_visible] => 1
            [is_variation] => 1
            [is_taxonomy] => 1
        )

    [pa_difficulte] => Array
        (
            [...]
        )

)

I expect to got the current attribute inside [pa_support].

Comment: what data did you expect to get here, can you be more specific please?

Answer (score 1):

'raw_woocommerce_price' was not the hook that I need.

Using instead these hooks was the way to go.

Why? Because these hooks have the product's instance as the second parameter. There, it got all information I need to got further.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'return_custom_price', $product, 10, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_get_regular_price', 'return_custom_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_get_sale_price', 'return_custom_price', 10, 2 );
function return_custom_price($price, $product) {
    global $post, $woocommerce;

    if( ! $product->product_type == 'variable'  ) return $price;

    switch (@$product->variation_data['attribute_pa_support']) {
        case "pdf" :
            return ($price * 0.5);
        break;
    }

    return $price;

}
```